# On Return Stack overflow Issue with Jobj

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a very wired issue that I can't figure out if it is a bug in Azure or I am doing something wrong. The following code causing a stackoverflow issue on the return.

```
[FunctionName("HttpTrigger1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        var array = JObject.FromObject(new {dd=1,ddd=2});
        var  errorresult = new ObjectResult(array);
        return  errorresult;
    }
```

No crash occurred everything is going fine on return I receive the following in my terminal.

```
   CollectionDataContractAttribute ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetNonDCTypeStableName(System.Type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetStableName(System.Type, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetCollectionStableName(System.Type, System.Type, System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetNonDCTypeStableName(System.Type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetStableName(System.Type, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetCollectionStableName(System.Type, System.Type, System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetNonDCTypeStableName(System.Type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetStableName(System.Type, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetCollectionStableName(System.Type, System.Type, System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetNonDCTypeStableName(System.Type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetStableName(System.Type, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetCollectionStableName(System.Type, System.Type, System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetNonDCTypeStableName(System.Type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetStableName(System.Type, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetCollectionStableName(System.Type, System.Type, System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetNonDCTypeStableName(System.Type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetStableName(System.Type, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetCollectionStableName(System.Type, System.Type, System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetNonDCTypeStableName(System.Type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetStableName(System.Type, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetCollectionStableName(System.Type, System.Type, System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetNonDCTypeStableName(System.Type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetStableName(System.Type, Boolean ByRef)
   ----- Repeated over and over :(
```

One important detail This happen when I add The Accept header, in postman, -->application/vnd.api+json If I removed the Accept header everything will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using application/json in postman it works properly with your code and it's not working with application/vnd.api+json.
In Visual Studio, I have created a FunctionApp with HttpTrigger and replaced with the following code you given.

```
[FunctionName("HttpTrigger1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var array = JObject.FromObject(new {dd=1,ddd=2});
            var  errorresult = new ObjectResult(array);
            return  errorresult;
        }
```

[image]

Then I have reproduced with your code as below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace FunctionAppfun
{
    public static class Function1
    {
         [FunctionName("HttpTrigger1")]
            public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
            {
                var array = JObject.FromObject(new { dd = 1, ddd = 2 });
                var errorresult = new ObjectResult(array);
                return errorresult;
            }
        }
    }
```

and I Have received error as you have.

Then, With below code and `application/vnd.api+json` it worked perfectly for me:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionAppfun
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]